# How would I remove duplicate characters or strings in a : separated list?

Tags: text-processing, scripting

For example,in `a:bc:d:a:hi:p:a` remove duplicate `a` and in `apple:orange:apple:.:pear:mango:.:apple` - remove duplicate `apple`

Comment: All of the duplicate apples? There should be only one left?  There should be no double colons `::` in the output?

Comment: the colons will stay. only the duplicate string between the colons : :: :.: need to be removed.

Comment: In your second example, why is `.` not also to be removed? It is a duplicate too.

Comment: @camh It is reasonable to believe that this is an oversight.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'd expect so, but it's also the only non-alphabetic value so perhaps there's another requirement waiting for us.

Comment: So this is subtly but importantly different from uniquefying a `$PATH` string, because you want to keep all the `:` and you apparently don't want to keep even one copy of each duplicate.  Pointing this out in the question (and showing the actual example outputs) would be good to help future readers that find this with a search realize exactly what the answers will do.

Answer (score 5):

GNU **awk** solution (all separators will be preserved):

```
s="apple:orange:apple:.:pear:mango:.:apple"
awk '{ len=split($0,a,/:|:\.:/,seps); 
       for(i=1;i<=len;i++) printf "%s%s",(!w[a[i]]++? a[i]:""),(i==len? "":seps[i]);
       print "" }' <<<"$s"
```

- `len=split($0,a,/:|:\.:/,seps)` - divide string into pieces separated by regex pattern `/:|:\.:/` and store the pieces in array `a` and the separator strings in the `seps` array.
- `len` - contains the number of elements/chunks created as a result of splitting

---

The output:

```
apple:orange::.:pear:mango:.:
```

Answer (score 5):

## Ordered Python Solution

If the order matters, here's what we can do in python as one-liner:

```
$ python -c 'import sys;from collections import OrderedDict; d=OrderedDict( (i,True) for i in sys.argv[1].split(":") );print ":".join(d.keys())'  'apple:orange:apple:.:pear:mango:.:apple'
apple:orange:.:pear:mango
```

A bit lengthy, so we could make it into a small script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import OrderedDict
import sys
d=OrderedDict( (i,True) for i in sys.argv[1].split(":") )
print ":".join(d.keys())
```

And use it as so:

```
$ ./uniq_tokens.py 'apple:orange:apple:.:pear:mango:.:apple'                                                                                                           
apple:orange:.:pear:mango
```

The way this works:

- we give the string we desire to process as command-line argument, hence we use `sys` module to refer to `sys.argv[1]`
- `sys.argv[1]` get's split into tokens using `:` as separator
- `(i,True) for i in sys.argv[1].split(":")` allows us to create list of tuples with two values, where `True` is just dummy value
- `OrderedDict` then takes those and creates a dictionary of key-value pairs. This is a "cheap" way to make [ordered set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6197522/3701431) with [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21103800/3701431) as alternative to dict comprehension. If string is already exists as key, it'll remain unique ([unless one does something unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5451361/3701431))
- `":".join()` will allow us to take all the tokens we split (hence we use `d.keys()` here),  and convert then back to a nice whole string joined with `:`
- print is self-explanatory.

## Unordered (but shorter) Python Solution

If the order doesn't matter, we can get a shorter solution (but this is more for fun rather than practical application - probably 99% of the time you want to preserve order of tokens):

```
$ python -c  'import sys;print ":".join(set(sys.argv[1].split(":")))'  'a:bc:d:a:hi:p:a'                                                                               
a:p:hi:d:bc
```

The way this works is simple:

- we pass the desired string as command-line argument, hence we need `import sys` to refer to first command-line argument as `sys.argv[1]`
- now, let's unwrap that second portion; `sys.argv[1].split(":")`  gives us a list of tokens out of what originally was a whole string, and we split using `:` as separator for individual tokens
- `set()` will take that list of strings mentioned above and give us unique values
- now, we need to convert this collection of strings back into one whole string, and that's why we use `":".join()` to splice all tokens together again using `:` as separator.
- `print` is self explanatory. Note that this is Python 2.7 syntax. Use `print()` for Python 3

And here's test with other strings:

```
$ python -c  'import sys;print ":".join(set(sys.argv[1].split(":")))'  'apple:orange:apple:.:pear:mango:.:apple'                                                       
orange:mango:pear:apple:.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Perl's hash data type to remove duplicates:

```
$ cat ./remove_dup.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $input = shift;
my %seen;

my $order=1;
foreach my $dir ( split /:/, $input ) {
        $seen{$dir} = $order++ unless ($seen{$dir})  ;
}
my $output =  join( ':',  sort { $seen{$a} <=> $seen{$b} } keys(%seen));
print $output . "\n";
```

Demo:

```
$ ./remove_dup.pl a:bc:d:a:hi:p:a
a:bc:d:hi:p
$ ./remove_dup.pl apple:orange:apple:.:pear:mango:.:apple
apple:orange:.:pear:mango
```

Answer (score 4):

A shell solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

rmdups () (
    IFS=':'
    for elem in $1; do
        # If $path already contains $elem, do nothing. Otherwise add
        # $elem to the end of $path (or set $path to $elem if $path was
        # empty).
        case "$path" in
            $elem|$elem:*|*:$elem:*|*:$elem) ;; # do nothing
            *) [ -n "$path" ] && path="$path:$elem" || path="$elem" ;;
        esac
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$path"
)

p='apple:apple:::orange:apple:.:pear:mango:.:apple'
rmdups "$p"
```

This is a shell function that removed duplicates from any `PATH`-like variable. By using `(...)` instead of `{...}` for the body of the function, we make sure that all variables inside the function are local (we need this to ensure that we don't pollute the environment of the caller with `elem`, `path` and the modified `IFS` variable). A `bash` function could declare these variables with `local` or `typeset` instead (`typeset` would work in both `bash` and `ksh93`).

The output of the above is

```
apple::orange:.:pear:mango
```

Comment: You can use `local IFS=':'`.  That works in bash at least, not sure if POSIX `sh` guarantees it.

Comment: @PeterCordes `local` is a `bash` extension.

Comment: First time seeing someone use `()` instead of `{}` for function body. Creative approach

Answer (score 3):

A `bash` solution:

```
strjoin() { local IFS="$1"; echo "${*:2}"; }
dedup() {
    declare -A valbag
    IFS=: read -r -a vals <<<"$1"
    for ((i=0; i < ${#vals[@]}; i++)); do
        (( valbag[${vals[i]}]++ > 0 )) && vals[i]=''
    done
    strjoin : "${vals[@]}"
}

$ dedup apple:orange:apple:.:pear:mango:.:apple
apple:orange::.:pear:mango::
$ dedup 'a:bc:d:a:hi:p:a'
a:bc:d::hi:p:
```

This meets the requirement from your comment of leaving all the colons in place and just emptying the duplicates between the colons.

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-liner `awk` solution.

```bsh
awk -F\: '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf(!arr[$i]++)?(i<2?"":":")$i:""; print ""}' infile
a:bc:d:hi:p
apple:orange:.:pear:mango
```

No, if you want to preserve the colons, then.

```bsh
awk -F\: '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf(!arr[$i]++)?(i<2?"":":")$i:":"; print ""}'
a:bc:d::hi:p:
apple:orange::.:pear:mango::
```

Or with while loop;

```bsh
awk -F\: '{i=0;while (NF>=++i) printf(!arr[$i]++)?(i<2?"":":")$i:":"; print ""}'
```